# If object not found then show default image as alternative

Tags: image, object, aurelia

I want to show a PDF to users on specific page .Therefore I used a OBJECT HTML tag for this purpose and its working fine .But if URL of PDF borken or changed then I am getting error that "PDF Is not loading and my alternate image is not loading .

I tried different method for setting this like "onerror" and srcset too but not resolve my issue.

```
<object data="my_url"> <img src="my_alternate_image"> </object>
```

If PDF corrupt unable to load or Link broken or changed then alternate image should be load .